# Dual boot is not working on windows 11

Tags: windows-11, dualboot

I have just installed elementaryOS on a partition of my harddrive. I can boot into either windows or elementary at will by intercepting the startup and changing my boot device but i expect windows to provide me with a boot menu option incase i forget. How can i enable boot menu through windows or UEFI?
Ive already checked startup settings and dual boot is enabled as i can see the time on boot screen, but i can only see one OS? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I've found it is far easier to setup for a boot menu through Linux + GRUB

Comment: It is also easier to set up operating systems you wish to test / review in a virtual machine. That will not damage the Windows 11 boot in any way.